# strange behaviour with php function and save in new txt in two line

Tags: php, text

I have this file `disponib.txt` with work schedule:

```
robert=1-am|3-pm|12-am
jane=2-pm|14-am|7-pm|9-pm|1-pm
leonard=1-am|14-pm
frank=1-am
```

and this is my code:

```
<?PHP
    $FileElenco = file("disponib.txt");
    for ($i=0; $i<count($FileElenco); $i++){
        $spezza_1 = explode("=",$FileElenco[$i]);
        $name = $spezza_1[0];        //es: robert
        $disponib = $spezza_1[1];        //es: 1-am|3-pm|12-am

        $disponib_1 = explode("|",$disponib);
        for ($x=0; $x<count($disponib_1); $x++){
            $spezza_2 = explode("-",$disponib_1[$x]);
            $day = (int)$spezza_2[0];        //es: 1
            $when = $spezza_2[1];            //es: am
            $ins_name = $name."(".$when.")";        //insert name with availability
            $fileout = "Days/g_".$day.".txt";
            $out = fopen($fileout,"a") or die("Impossible open the file!!");
            fwrite($out,$ins_name."<br>") or die("Impossible write on file!!");
            fclose($out) or die("Impossible close the file!!");
        }
    }
?>
```

But, when save, I find the file txt like this `(g_1.txt):`

```
robert(am
)<br>jane(pm)<br>leonard(am)<br>frank(am)
```

and not in one row like this:

```
robert(am)<br>jane(pm)<br>leonard(am)<br>frank(am)
```

Could you help me?

Comment: I'm suspecting some kind of special character in the original file. Try this `$ins_name = $name . "(". trim($when). ")";

Answer (score 2):

The new lines are coming from your original file.

By default, `file` will include the new line characters from the input file in each array entry it creates, but you can use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` option to avoid that. This should fix it:

```
$FileElenco = file("disponib.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Comment: I'm confused about why you suggested not importing them with file() but your solution is just to add an optional argument to file()

Comment: @KodosJohnson oh, bad phrasing on my part. by "them" I mean "the newlines". I'll edit to clarify that.

Comment: @KodosJohnson thanks for pointing that out. Hopefully my revision makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you Don't Panic! It's perfect! :-)

Comment: Cool, that looks better.